# AVCaptureSession slow to start iOS8 - Xamarin

Tags: ios, ios8, xamarin.ios, xamarin, avcapturesession

I am using the sample source code from Xamarin.com for iOS which reads QR codes using an AVCaptureSession. The AvCaptureSession however is taking 10+ seconds to launch overtime. I am using an iPhone 5S and open my camera is very quick so i don't understand why opening the session should be so slow.

The delay happens during StartRunning() call in the example below.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/QRchestra/

Comment: 10+ seconds sounds a bit much. what else is the code doing? Starting a capture session typically takes around 5s though (iPad 2, so fairly old hardware).

Comment: Its these tock code from example above.